# Informing client that more information is available for authorized users in REST API

Tags: rest, http

Is there a standard way to let the consumer of a RESTful API to know that an endpoint has more information available if authorization is provided? To give an example, such a response could be received to a `GET` request to `https://example.com/users/10` if no authorization was provided.

As far as I know, there isn't a HTTP status for that scenario. Closest I can think of is `207 Multi-Status` with `200 OK` and `401 Unauthorized` sub-statuses, but `207` is not really standard, and would require `XML` per definition, which I'm not willing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to REST the big problem lies in the fact that there's almost no standardization.

Personally I've no clear solution to your problem but `207` sounds good and might be the one way to go.

The second one is to always return the whole entity with only these field filled that do not require authorization and (unfortunately) info about the authorization required is stated clearly in the API docs (yes, I know that API what you should provider according to HATEOAS is just a root URI but I just don't think that it's enough).

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but the one I feared would be the correct one. I'll give it a moment in case someone comes up with a magical solution, but otherwise I think this is the correct answer. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Sure, thanks for upvoting. That's a true problem despite REST is so popular it has almost no standards :(